# Read email imap php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, imap

I am using PHP - Codeigniter (Peeker Library) as back-end  and using IMAP to fetch emails from multiple email addresses.

We have some complex search criteria to query against imap folder, to increase performance of the script we only search on new emails and storing mailbox name,unique id (unique in mailbox), some header information in MySQL table.

I came up with two problems :

1. How can i keep track on `Deleted / Moved` items ?
2. Is there any way to determine attachment exists or not ? ( Because header information doesn't give any clue to attachment indicator , i tried to use `imap_fetchstructure` but it reads the entire message including attachment which takes a long time to process )

**Note :**

> I am running this script on back end with a regular interval ( But not
>    a cron job, an external application will initialize the script on a regular
>   interval ).Additionally i am doing all these with PHP with its on limitations.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in IMAP, there is no requirement which would imply that `FETCH BODYSTRUCTURE` would have transfer complete message data with attachments. Either your assumption is wrong, or your IMAP library has a grave bug, or you are using a wrong function here.

Second, you mentioned keeping track of UIDs but have not said anything about the `UIDVALIDITY`. Read [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) to understand what it means. There is no way you could implement an application talking IMAP correctly without knowing the protocol. Further pointers are also given in [RFC 4549](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4549).

Your third question is about asking for deleted or moved items. In baseline IMAP, you cannot do that. The only way to know what messages have been deleted and which are the new arrivals is to track the UIDs explicitly -- assuming the `UIDVALIDITY` was given and did not change, you compare the list of UIDs since the last time with what you got now, and see which are new and which are gone. Again, read the RFCs, they contain answers to all of your questions as well as suggestions on how to optimize the synchronization process. There's also a [thesis about IMAP](http://trojita.flaska.net/msc-thesis.pdf) which goes into much more detail on how to further improve the protocol chat and what extensions are relevant. This is not an easy project, though.

Comment: Why are you going too much ?? the php function `imap_fetchstructure` will read the contents of email body in order to analyze the structure. You are saying too much about the protocol, but i am talking about the language that i am using. on your first para you said that i am using some wrong function or the imap library have a bug. Could you please explain little bit more ?

Comment: All right. The PHP function ``imap_fetchstructure`` offloads the interesting work to c-client's ``mail_fetchstructure_full``. That function (in the ``c-client`` library from the UW-IMAPD) sends an IMAP command which fetches the ``BODY`` thing -- however, as RFC 3501 defines, this is actually a **structure** of a message body, not the full raw text of the message itself. Therefore I'm saying that calling PHP's ``imap_fetchstructure`` does **not** read the contents of a message body over the IMAP connection.

Comment: Okay, Then why it takes a long time (Comparatively ) to read messages with attachment ?I am not saying that `imap_fetchstructure` downloads everything physically.Ex. If there is zip file with 12 mB as attachment and if `imap_fetchstructure` only reads its Content Type,Size,name etc then its fine.

Comment: I don't have a crystall ball, so I don't know what takes long time on your system, nor why it is so. You haven't shown any measurements, sorry.

Comment: Sorry for that. Still i guess that it trying to read the contents. Whatever it is,it takes long time process.

Answer (score 0):

why you are not using [php imap](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) ? it's simple and very fast compared with peeker library and php imap always get new email.

Comment: Peeker is made with `PHP IMAP`.