# how imap_fetchstructure in PHP works?

Tags: php, imap

I was trying to read headers using PHP IMAP functions and save into mysql database.

Sample code to check attachment exists

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to mail: ' . imap_last_error());
$struct = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$uid,FT_UID);
$existAttachments = existAttachment($struct);

function existAttachment($part){
    if (isset($part->parts)){
        foreach ($part->parts as $partOfPart){
            existAttachment($partOfPart);
        }
    }
    else{
        if (isset($part->disposition)){
            if ($part->disposition == 'attachment'){
                echo '<p>' . $part->dparameters[0]->value . '</p>';

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine but i noticed that it takes a long time to return the content.

**Does it pull the whole content or just the message structure ? Or is there any way to detect attachment exists or not ?**

Thanks.

Comment: what is your question? why taken so long? or the function's mechanism ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor SO feels that my question is invalid, so i need to use small hacks to post the question, Question Edited.

Comment: I have already answered your question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051633/read-email-imap-php .

Comment: @JanKundrát Welcome, Yes i know that. But check the Bold part. I need to have some detailed explanation because there are many user commented that it pulls the entire content,even on php.net user notes section.

Comment: Then read the PHP's and c-client's code for yourself -- the function names I gave you in the other thread should help you find them without much trouble.